# PL/SQL engine in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a PL/SQL engine in SQLDeveloper?

Answer (score 10):

You can run PL/SQL in SQL Developer just as you can in SQL*Plus. I'd say the 'engine' is in the database though, not in the client.

Comment: I know that some tools like "Oracle forms" has the "PLSQL engine" within the tools...I want to know if it's the case with SQL Developer.

Comment: @Joel No that's not the case with SQL Devloper. SQLDeveloper is a thin client and would rely on the Database server's engine. Developer suite comes with its own engine since Developer suite provides way to create local oc4j instance to deploy and test the forms instead of doing that in the application server level.

Answer (score 3):

SQLDeveloper is a Java application that connects to your Oracle database schema through JDBC, it does not have, or even needs, its own PL/SQL engine.

Answer (score 2):

No,SQLDeveloper does not have a PL/SQL engine embedded in it.

You login to an oracle DB, author your PL/SQL procs and tell OracleDB to execute/debug them. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer can run PL/SQL code.

Wrap the PL/SQL code in `BEGIN` & `END` and it will run fine

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Forms and Reports use their *own* PL/SQL engines.
Although syntactically they are identical, they are not the same as the database engine and uses a different set of libraries. Not all the advanced features of the database engine are available to the Forms and Reports PL/SQL engines and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

SQLDeveloper is a Java application that acts as a pure JDBC client to an Oracle database; therefore it is not a PLSQL interpreter(engine) by itself, but in case you were wondering where the syntax validation messages were coming from in the GUI, it does ship with a SQL/PLSQL parser generated in Java using Antlr (http://www.antlr.org/about.html) from a custom SQL/PLSQL grammar.